# Knockout Paged grid example automatically updating view

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js, datagrid

I'm new to KO and I'm working on a grid (data table) following the [Paged grid example](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/grid.html).

This is my code:
    var initialData = $.parseJSON(response);
    enter code here`response=null;

```
var PagedGridModel = function(items) {
    this.items = ko.observableArray(items);

    this.gridViewModel = new ko.simpleGrid.viewModel({
        data: this.items,
        columns: [
            { headerText: "checkbox", 
                rowText: function (item) {
                    return '<input name="select-product" type="checkbox"/>'
                    if (item.checked)
                        return baseHtml+' checked'+endingHtml
                    else
                        return baseHtml+endingHtml
                }
            },
            { headerText: "name", rowText: "name" },
            { headerText: "description", rowText: "description" },
            { headerText: "category", rowText: "category" },
            { headerText: "type", rowText: "type" },
        ],
        pageSize: 20
    });
    };

var myPagedGridModel = new PagedGridModel(initialData)
ko.applyBindings(myPagedGridModel);
```

And it produces a result like that.

[image: my ko grid]

Now I would like that when changing the Model's 'checkbox' attribute, It updates the view. And vice-versa, selecting the view's checkbox to update my model. Something like this:

> initialData[0].checked=true;

It seems what I need to do is declare the model as Observable, but I'm not sure how to do that on this context.
Finally, I think this library is relevant for this case: http://knockoutjs.com/examples/resources/knockout.simpleGrid.3.0.js

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ernestbofill/QSRBR/6145/)
On the fiddle I had some problem with the externals but pleas take into account the fist SimpleGrid.3.0.js outside the fiddle it works with that one alone.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Ernest.

Comment: Could you set this up in a snippet or jsfiddle? I'd like to see your markup/binding.

Comment: @xdumaine just edited and added the fiddle http://knockoutjs.com/examples/resources/knockout.simpleGrid.3.0.js

Comment: That fiddle doesn't have the checkbox portion in it, which is the relative part.

Comment: Argh! I see, it's weird I did see the checkboxes when I linked it first place. i'll review it. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @xdumaine, I updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ernestbofill/QSRBR/6145/